# Artifact Registry - GCP, Unable to use set-cleanup-policy, having trouble with json file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cicd, google-artifact-registry

https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/repositories/cleanup-policy

this clearly states, to create a json file like this -

```
[
  {
    "name": "my-policy",
    "action": {"type": "Delete"},
    "condition": {
      "versionAge": 30d
    }
  }
]
```

but when i do, i get this -

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (InvalidUserInputError): Could not read JSON file retention.json: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 6 column 21 (char 104)
```

i have tried removing d, making it the whole thing a str, but nothing works.

i have tried removing d, making it the whole thing a str, but nothing works.

Comment: the issue is that the google doc seems to give an invalid json, what needs to be done to not give this error is to put a 30d between "
```
[
  {
    "name": "my-policy",
    "action": {"type": "Delete"},
    "condition": {
      "versionAge": "30d"
    }
  }
]
```
but even so a issue remain 

ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'additionalProperties'

Comment: correct. So, i am trying to find a better way